# TensorFlow, batchwise indexing (first dimension) and sorting

Tags: python, sorting, tensorflow, indexing, keras

I've got a params tensor with shape `(?,368,5)`, as well as a query tensor with shape `(?,368)`. The query tensor stores indices for sorting the first tensor.

The required output has shape: `(?,368,5)`. Since I need it for a loss function in a neural network, the used operations should stay differentiable. Also, at runtime the size of the first axis `?` corresponds to the batchsize.

So far I experimented with `tf.gather` and `tf.gather_nd`, however
`tf.gather(params,query)` results in a tensor with shape `(?,368,368,5)`.

The query tensor is achieved by performing:

```
query = tf.nn.top_k(params[:, :, 0], k=params.shape[1], sorted=True).indices
```

Overall, I try to sort the params tensor by the first element on the third axis (for kind of a chamfer distance). At last to mention is, that I work with the `Keras` framework.

Comment: What was wrong with `tf.gather_nd`? It should do what you want.

Comment: {ValueError}indices.shape[-1] must be <= params.rank, but saw indices shape [?,368,5] for loss with input shapes: [?,368,5],[?,368]

Comment: How are you trying to call `tf.gather_nd`? According to the error message `saw indices shape [?,368,5]` but you said that your indices tensor has shape `(?, 368)`.

Comment: tf.gather_nd(params, query) as found on the api https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd. Sorry copied wrong from the interpreter. {ValueError}indices.shape[-1] must be <= params.rank, but saw indices shape [?,368] and params shape [?,368,5] for loss with input shapes: [?,368,5],[?,368]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the indices of the first dimension to `query` in order to use it with `tf.gather_nd`. Here is a way to do it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    params = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 368, 5])
    query = tf.nn.top_k(params[:, :, 0], k=params.shape[1], sorted=True).indices
    n = tf.shape(params)[0]
    # Make tensor of indices for the first dimension
    ii = tf.tile(tf.range(n)[:, tf.newaxis], (1, params.shape[1]))
    # Stack indices
    idx = tf.stack([ii, query], axis=-1)
    # Gather reordered tensor
    result = tf.gather_nd(params, idx)
    # Test
    out = sess.run(result, feed_dict={params: np.random.rand(10, 368, 5)})
    # Check the order is correct
    print(np.all(np.diff(out[:, :, 0], axis=1) <= 0))
    # True
```