# tensorflow tf.gather_nd to handle unknow dimention

Tags: tensorflow

any simple way to implement below code,
especially handle unknow dimention, i want to add this code to loss function.Thanks.

```
result =[]
for i in range(0,x.shape[0]):
    tmp2 = tf.gather_nd(x[i], y[i])
    result.append(tmp2)
finalResult = tf.stack(result)
```

---

example

x shape=(?,3,2)

y shape= (?,1)

```
x :
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]

 [[12 13]
  [14 15]
  [16 17]]...]

y :
[[1]
 [0]
 [2]...]

finalResult :
[[ 2  3]
 [ 6  7]
 [16 17]...]
```

Comment: I think your problem is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50605059/1782792), take a look at the answer I posted there and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jdehesa's reply is helpful. Thanks so much.
have to add the indices of the first dimension to query.
(By the way, i made a mistake in loss function. it has to be differentiable.
but it's another issue.) anyway, thanks again.